# Postgresql - unexplained syntax error on json operand

Tags: json, postgresql

Hoping a fresh pair of eyes can spot what I'm doing wrong or point out where I can investigate my problem further. I am creating a function that includes a parameter passed as a json string.

Using the json operator `->` to access a data element within the json reports a syntax error that is confounding me. Here is my function (in brief):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createUser(  
  email_f character varying(50),  
  mobile_f integer,  
  salt_f character(16),   
  hash_f character(16),  
  encryption_f smallint,  
  iterations_f smallint,  
  fnam_f character varying(16),  
  lnam_f character varying(16),  
  nickname_f character varying(16),   
  fb_f json  
) RETURNS json AS $$  
/* Example /me response from FB  
{   
  id: "101...", email: "test@test.com", verified: true,  
  name: "test testlast", first_name: "test", last_name: "testlast", gender: "male",  
  link: "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/101.../",  
  locale: "en_US", timezone: -5, updated_time: "2014-07-01T14:48:27+0000"  
}  
*/
BEGIN  
  IF fnam_f IS NULL THEN  
    SET fnam_f = fb_f->'first_name';  
    SET lnam_f = fb_f->'last_name';  
  END IF;  
  INSERT INTO users (email,mobile,salt,hash,encryption,iteration,username,fbid)  
    SELECT email_f,mobile_f,salt_f,hash_f,encryption_f,iteration_f,nickname_f,null  
    RETURNING row_to_json(row(*));  
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Running this query returns a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->"
LINE 24:  SET fnam_f = fb_f->'first_name';
```

I find this confusing because I seem to be using the json operand correctly according to documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Thanks

Comment: Post the output of `select version()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For variables assignement, use [`:=`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) instead:

```
fnam_f := fb_f->'first_name';
lnam_f := fb_f->'last_name';
```

The [SET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) statement is used to change a run-time parameters.

Comment: good eye. I'm coming from mostly T-SQL background. Would have been nice if Postgres error had identified the real issue.